# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else on <form>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, syntax-error

Please don't hate me for posting a question, which to all of you, is probably the easiest thing ever. Started programming a few days ago.

Trying to create a really simple form with username/password and a button that checks the inputs to be true. If false it will give an alert:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input id="usrnm" type="text" name="username">
    <input id="passw" type="password" name="password">
    <input id="bttn1" type="button" value="Register!" onclick="register">
</form>
```

**Scripts:**

```
<script>
    function register(){
        validateForm();
    }
</script>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var usrnm = document.forms["usrnm"]["username"].value;
        var passw = document.forms["passw"]["password"].value;

        if(usrnm == null || usrnm == ""); {
            alert("Please choose a username!");
            return false;
        }
        else if(passw == null || passw == "") {
            alert("Please choose a password!");
            return false;
        }
        else(usrnm !== null) {
            alert("Thank you for registering!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else" from the "else if" statement line. Removing it, gives me the same error on the next "else" statement.

Comment: `onclick="register"` is missing `()` to invoke the function

Comment: Thank you for adding this. Made it much quicker to correct everything. Its all working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove ; in the if statement

`if(usrnm == null || usrnm == "");` must be `if(usrnm == null || usrnm == "")`

Comment: I now get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" on the **else(usrnm !== null) {** line

Comment: you cannot use a condition in else statement it must be either else if(usrnm !== null) or else